# How to join meshes without interfering with modifiers?

Tags: modifiers

I have made a character mesh and utilized the mirror modifier to get the arms, legs and torso to be symmetrical.
[image: Character Model (Before joining)]

Once I try to join all of the seperate meshes, the mirror modifier wears off and  it ends up looking like this /
[image: Meshes (Joined)]

This looks significantly creepier than the first image and I was wondering if anybody knew how to prevent this from happening. Thank you in advance for the feedback.

Comment: hello, maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Modifier will be used from the object selected while you press Join (or Ctrl+J) in Object mode. One way to work this out is to apply modifiers before joining. Also looks like you need to press Ctrl+A > Scale in Object mode with all selected and then recalculate normals

Comment: It's also important to watch out for the origins position.